# Как запретить сайту отображаться в IE6?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

Можно ли как-то запретить сайту отображаться в IE6? Можеть есть какой-то скрипт, который проверяет, если браузер IE6, то выводить сообщение и далее не загружать сайт вообще? Если нет такого скрипта, подскажите хотя бы как реализовать.

Comment: спасибо за ответы, в итоге решил проблему с помощью php, определил браузер, ну и если это IE, то перенаправляю на страницу скачивания одного из 3 браузеров (opera,ff,chrome), только вот проблемка маленькая осталась, мой код блокирует все IE и перенаправляет на скачивание даже с IE9 =) вот так...

Comment: ну так поставьте мне плюс. это ведь как раз то что я посоветовал

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте условные комментарии для IE

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="http://opera.com"</script>
<![endif]-->;
```

[Position:fixed в Internet Explorer](http://cleverscript.ru/css/cross-brouser-html/4-position-fixed.html)

Answer (score 3):

[Определение версии браузера на js](http://www.google.by/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8+%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0+%D0%BD%D0%B0+js#hl=ru&sa=X&ei=3jy2TumTBM27hAfc2sCeBA&ved=0CBcQvwUoAQ&q=%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8+%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0+%D0%BD%D0%B0+js&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=e484a72d26b74e6f&biw=1680&bih=938)
[Остановить загрузку страницы на js](http://www.google.by/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8+%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0+%D0%BD%D0%B0+js#sclient=psy-ab&hl=ru&source=hp&q=%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D1%83+%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B+%D0%BD%D0%B0+js&pbx=1&oq=%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D1%83+%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B+%D0%BD%D0%B0+js&aq=f&aqi=&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=71562l75428l0l75937l28l23l0l0l0l19l316l4819l0.8.14.1l23l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=e484a72d26b74e6f&biw=1680&bih=938)

Answer (score 2):

Может это конечно и немного глупо, но если у вас серверное приложение (а не html-ки) то можно на сервере распарсить header-ы и в зависимости от браузера выдавать страничку с нужным содержимым

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] - вернет строку в которой описан браузер и доп инфа по нему, разбирайте ее и ищите нежелательные вхождения, ну а дальше по условию отправляйте на страничку загрузки какого нить современного браузера))) или сами решайте.
```

Answer (score 0):

Для этого можно также использовать условные комментарии.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
body { display: none; }
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: это конечно вариант. Но лучше уж вывести что-то поинформативней) Или редирект на довнлоад страничку фф или хрома или оперы.